# select value from subfield that is inside an array

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON object that looks something like this:

```
{
    "a": [{
        "name": "x",
        "group": [{
            "name": "tom",
            "publish": true
        },{
            "name": "joe",
            "publish": true
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "y",
        "group": [{
            "name": "tom",
            "publish": false
        },{
            "name": "joe",
            "publish": true
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to select all the entries where `publish=true` and create a simplified JSON array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "x"
    "groupName": "tom"
  },
  {
    "name": "x"
    "groupName": "joe"
  },
  {
    "name": "y"
    "groupName": "joe"
  }  
]
```

I've tried many combinations but the fact that group is an array seems to prevent each from working. Both in this specific case as well as in general, how do you do a deep select without loosing the full hierarchy?

Comment: The output shown looks to me like you _want_ to lose the hierarchy -- you're throwing away the outer `a`, for example, in your sample output. What am I missing?

Comment: In this case I'm not interested in maintaining the hierarchy.  I was asking a general question as there are times when I want to search and match deep into the tree w/o loosing the full context.  I'm still learning the jq syntax and trying to understand how it works *ahead* of time.

Comment: Neither answer currently describes how to "do a deep select without losing the full hierarchy", yet you've accepted one of the two (effectively-equivalent) answers as acceptable. So I'm still a bit confused about what the intent of that verbiage in the question was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
jq '.[]|map(
      .name as $n
      | .group[]
      | select(.publish==true)
      | {name:$n,groupname:.name}
    )' file.json
```

Comment: Here, there's no need for to_entries, which makes things unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: why does it make things inefficient (compared to alternatives)? I think the use of `map()` here, instead of list aggregation as in the other answer, should definitely perform better on bigger input files. If I can further optimize it by replacing `to_entries`, I'm happy to do it, but I would like to know why

Comment: You can replace `to_entries[].value` by `.[]`.

Comment: Sure, that would save a few keystrokes (and I can do that later), but I'm just curious about the negative performance impacts. If `to_entries.value` would not perform more ore less the same as `.[]` I would be surprised. I'm asking because in (my) real world examples, the key is almost always interesting data and therefore I'm just used to `to_entries`

Comment: to_entries has to do a lot of work, taking both time and space, whereas .[] does almost nothing.

Comment: Ok, if you say that. I've changed it

Comment: For the record: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/6306ac89667cf35f47ddc40aa0630546c57e387f/src/builtin.jq#L23

Answer (score 5):

Using `<expression> as $varname` lets you store a value in a variable before going deeper into the hierarchy.

```
jq -n '
[inputs[][]
 | .name as $group
 | .group[]
 | select(.publish == true)
 | {name, groupName: $group}
]' <input.json
```

Answer (score 2):

A shorter, effective alternative:

```
.a | map({name, groupname: (.group[] | select(.publish) .name)})
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sAq7JexPDw)</sup>